# Google Drive Java API V3 delete custom property

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API for Java with a service account and I want to delete costume properties which were set by myself.

At https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration I read that I need to update the file with a map where I put the key with a null value.

`(files.update with {'properties':{'key':null}})`

my code looks like this:

```
File body = new File();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(propertyName, null);
body.setProperties(map);
service.files().update(fileId, body).execute();
```

The JSON content is `{properties={test=null}}`

The above code works without any exception, but the property is still set. How can I delete the property?

Comment: You can try to update the files using [`Files: update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) if it works in your case. It is stated in the documentation that `properties` are collection of arbitrary key-value pairs which are visible to all apps. And entries with null values are cleared in update and copy requests. Another possible way is using the v2 of the Drive API in where there is an option of [deleting properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/delete). Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried to update the file with the new metadata, but unfortently it does not effect the property. The update call works without any problems. I can update the value, but it does not delete the property, when setting the value to null.

Comment: Oh and I need to use version 3 for this project, therefore i cant use Version 2 of the API.

Comment: I just did a quick test of this using v3. In my case, although the key was not cleared as stated in the documentation, the value was set to null or at least to something that displayed as null.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Fromapi V2 to v3 there are few changes are done while deleting, update properties and some other function calls. Please verify 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#methods
In this page you can find 
properties.delete, properties.get and properties.insert 

for deleteproperties in v3

PRIVATE: files.update with {'appProperties':{'key':null}}

PUBLIC: files.update with {'properties':{'key':null}}

Thanks