# Google Drive api v3 (java): Deleting a resource property does not work

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API for Java (v3-rev111-1.23). I'm trying to remove a property from a resource. 
I followed this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#methods

This is the code I wrote:

```
Drive service = getDriveService();
File file = new File();
Map<String,String> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("propA", null);
file.setProperties(properties);

file = service.files().update(fileId, file).execute();
```

The problem is that the property is never cleared.  Remains with the previous value.

If I write the generated json with:

```
System.out.println(service.files().update(fileId, file).getJsonContent());
```

I get:

{properties={propA=null}}

Using the same code to add a new property like:

```
properties.put("test", "yes");
```

I get:

{properties={test=yes}}

and it works properly.

Has someone faced and solved this problem?

I read this post [Google Drive Java API V3 delete custom property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739322/google-drive-java-api-v3-delete-custom-property) from 2016, but no solution was given.

---

More details:

Using the try-its of the web (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) I could create properties, modify them and even delete them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I can share that might help you, using the Try-its:

I created a file using [Files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) and created a custom property

```
appProperties{
  "supersaiyan": "yes"
}
```

Then I deleted it using [Files.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update):

```
appProperties{
  "supersaiyan": null
}
```

When I tried to fetch the `appProperties`, I got `{}` which means successfully deleted.

Comment: I also used the try-its without being able to replicate the problem. I was able to add and remove properties to the same resource. I could see how that property was deleted by listing from the console.